# Cassandra Mapper: cannot insert nullable types

Tags: c#, cassandra

I'm trying to insert a POCO with nullable types (like DateTime? LastAccessed) using an IMapper, but getting an exception stating:

```
   Nullable object must have a value.
```

StackTrace is:

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at lambda_method(Closure , UserEntity`1 )
   at Cassandra.Mapping.Mapper.InsertIfNotExistsAsync[T](T poco, CqlQueryOptions queryOptions)
   at Cassandra.Mapping.Mapper.InsertIfNotExists[T](T poco, CqlQueryOptions queryOptions)
   ...(my function)
```

The primary key for the table (an id) has a value, and it's not a nullable type (of course)..

Why can't I insert with specifying all the columns that I need?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Cassandra doesn't deal well with nulls.  Inserting a null value actually creates a tombstone for that column.  So it's best to avoid doing it if at all possible.

Secondly, the [CQL data types to C# types](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/csharp-driver/reference/csharpType2Cql3Datatypes_r.html) section of the driver documentation does not have a match for a `DateTime` (let alone a `DateTime?`).  Are you trying to map that to a timestamp in Cassandra?  If so, you will need to use the `DateTimeOffset` type, and it cannot be nullable.

Comment: regarding the DateTime - I missed it somehow so thanks for that. Secondly, I knew that about nulls. That's why I was hoping IMapper would handle nullable types. I guess I would just have to use the core statements for INSERTs without specifying the columns I don't need (a handful of those)..